# delay using promise instead of setTimeout

Tags: promise, settimeout

I know the output of the code but can anyone please tell me when setTimeout will be called please...

```
function delay(time) {
    
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();            
        }, time);
    })
}


delay(3000).then(function () {
    console.log("run after 3000 seconds")
})
```

Comment: After approximately 3000ms? (so 3 not 3000 seconds). Not really sure what you're asking please clarify your question.

Comment: `setTimeout(…)` is called immediately (from within `delay(…)`). `resolve()` is called 3 seconds after that. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: 3000s is just a typo , I just want to know when the setTimeout will be pushed into the callback queue.
1) when i am returning
2) when i typing .then()